# Is there a way to save data to pdf from parallel port?

Tags: printing, parallel-port

I have legacy device with only parallel port that connect to printer , is there a way to connect the device to windows and save the data as pdf?

Comment: The parallel port is just a port, it doesn't mean any type of printer. Does your device know at least the printer it is goint to work with?

Comment: I don't think so. it just send data over LPT port. it is currently connected to a dot matrix printer but i want to replace that wit a PC.